# I am trying to use classic bluetooth device in iOS by using react-native-bluetooth-classic i am getting Error Method not implemented. on android works

Tags: ios, react-native, bluetooth

```
 try {
      let paired = await RNBluetoothClassic.getBondedDevices();
      setPairedDevice(paired);
      let unpaired = await RNBluetoothClassic.startDiscovery();
      setBluetoothDevice(unpaired);
      setLoading(false);
    } catch (err) {
      console.log('error:', err);
      setLoading(false);
    }
```

I am trying to scan bluetooth classic device in IOS it perfecly works in android i have done all required step for ios as mentioned in documentation. this method works

```
await RNBluetoothClassic.isBluetoothEnabled();
```

but when scanning bluetooth

```
await RNBluetoothClassic.startDiscovery()
```

Erro

[Error: Method not implemented.]

not working

```
 "react-native-bluetooth-classic": "^1.60.0-rc.26",
```

Comment: You'll also notice that all the methods are documented with which platforms they are supported.   Even if your device becomes MFi certified, the methods will not be supported as Apple requires discovery and pairing be completed through the settings.  Unless they've updated the CoreBluetooth library, which I couldn't see when I took a look.

Answer (score 3):

Apps cannot scan or access classic Bluetooth devices on iOS unless the device you are trying to communicate with is MFi certified and your app includes the matching protocol string in your `info.plist` file.

Comment: how to add MFI certificate.

Comment: The hardware needs to include an MFi chipset.  This would entail finding an MFi licensee manufacturer and working with them on the hardware.  Your organisation also needs to join the MFi program in order to register the protocol string to work with the hardware. https://mfi.apple.com/en/how-it-works